# Flutter IOS how to iterate camera/pictures folder?

Tags: flutter

I want to iterate all photo that my iOS device have.
I got path of camera by below code , but I can't iterate it all ,
how can I iterate all of camera image in IOS?

```
new Directory(externalDir.toString()+"/camera/pictures")
    .create()
    .then((Directory directory) 
    {
      print("rendered directory is.........."+directory.toString());
      _fetchFiles(directory);
      print("rendered directory is!!!!!"+directory.path);
    });
```

_fetchFiles(Directory dir) async {

```
print("directory :fetch file come is $dir");

    //  List<dynamic> listImage = List<dynamic>();
    dir.list().forEach((element) {
      print("directory"+element.toString());
    });
    print("directory fetchfiles come");
    return true;
  }
```

Comment: found anything yet?